# Trigger SharePoint workflow when one column is edited

Tags: sharepoint

I have built an inventory database in SharePoint 2016. I want to create an approval workflow that is automatically triggered when the "Room" field is edited.

I'm trying to keep this clean. The option to trigger workflows when an item is edited, starts the WF when I update any other column. I tried to mitigate this with the "wait for" clause, and that just leaves a WF hanging until the condition is met.

Any ideas? The Room cloumn is single line text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> that just leaves a WF hanging until the condition is met

A "waiting" workflow is just a record in a SQL table. It is not tying up resources while it is waiting.

Otherwise, you can have a workflow that runs on Create that updates a non-displayed column with the initial Room value. Then have a workflow that runs on Change that compares the two columns. If they are the same, it just exits, otherwise it does what ever work is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, we can create an event receiver and start workflow in the event receiver base on some conditions.

[Starting a SharePoint workflow from code (Event Receiver)](https://zimmergren.net/starting-a-sharepoint-workflow-from-code-event-receiver/)